# C++ Will use of pointers in vectors potentially cause dangling pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, memory-management

```c++
class Thing {
    public:
        Thing();
        void dosomething(int i);
};
Thing::Thing() {};
void Thing::dosomething(int i) {
    std::cout << i << "\n";
};

std::vector<Thing*> thingsList;

Thing a = {}; 
Thing b = {};
Thing c = {};

thingsList.push_back(&a);
thingsList.push_back(&b);
thingsList.push_back(&c);

thingsList[0]->dosomething(2);
```

The code above compiles and works for me. But I am wondering if it could cause problems. Consider that vectors reallocate its memory array as the vector grows/shrinks. Isn't it possible that as the vector dynamically reallocates that you would end up with dangling pointers? Or do vectors handle this problem?

Is it always better to use unique_ptr instead?

Comment: "*I am wondering if it could cause problems*" - in this example, no, unless you later access the `vector` elements after `a`, `b`, and `c` have gone out of scope, invalidating the pointers that the `vector` is holding.

Comment: Vector reallocations won't cause dangling pointers. The only thing that causes a dangling pointer is the pointer living longer than the thing it's pointing to. Vectors are nothing to do with that.

Comment: `vector` will maintain the values, even if it grows or shrinks. If you make sure that all the pointers in the vector point to memory that lives as long as the vector, you're fine.

Comment: Using pointers can definitely cause problems, but std::vector won't be the cause of them.

Comment: I think you're getting confused with a different issue, if you have pointers to the elements in the vector, then vector reallocation can invalidate those pointers, but that's not the case in the code above.

Comment: If the vector OWNS the items that are in it (and therefore responsible for deleting them at the end of the life of those objects), the vector should be `vector<unique_ptr<Thing>>`.

Comment: It would improve the question to post real code

Answer (score 4):

This is fine

```
Thing t0, t1;
vector<Thing*> v;
v.push_back(&t0);
v.push_back(&t1);
```

even if the second `push_back` causes reallocation `v[0]` will still be pointing at `t0`.

This is not fine

```
Thing t0, t1;
vector<Thing> v;
v.push_back(t0);
Thing* tp = &v[0];
v.push_back(t1);
```

Here the second `push_back` may invalidate the `tp` pointer, because `tp` is pointing to the internals of the vector which will be deleted if reallocation occurs.